# Transition between two Fragments with Sound on Button Click

Tags: android, button, audio

Two fragments with a button in each one. If I click the button provided the first fragment, it will play a music and move to the second fragment and if I press the button shown in the second fragment, the first fragment reappears starting the second piece of music and stopping the first piece. I have provided here only the codes here. The app successfully installs both on AVD and real device but sounds didn't play. Please help..

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Fragment1());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

First Fragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);

        final Button buttonFragment1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonFragmentId1);
        final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.a);
        buttonFragment1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Fragment2());
                ft.commit();

                if(mp1.isPlaying()==true){
                    mp1.pause();
                    mp1.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Second Fragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    MediaPlayer mp2 = new MediaPlayer();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
        final Button buttonFragment2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonFragmentId2);
        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.a);
        buttonFragment2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Fragment1());
                ft.commit();

             if(mp2.isPlaying()==true){
                 mp2.pause();
                 mp2.seekTo(0);
             }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can just make the first line a summary of the problem you are having. Wasn't very clear at first what the problem was.

Comment: HEARTFELT THANKS TO YOU! Actually I am recently learning fragments, am a novice. I made two fragments, each of them contains a button. If I press the button of the first fragment, it will play a music and take me to the second fragment; as I click the button in the second fragment, it stops the first music, starting a new piece of music, and takes me back to the first fragment again. That was my intention but everything was successfully launched but no music played.